# use of variable to configure proxy_pass fails. why?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

What am I misunderstanding about nginx variables and how they work?

The first location /atlas/ fails to send the request to the upstream server with the following nginx error:

```
backoffice  | 2024/03/12 22:10:19 [error] 17#17: *9 invalid URL prefix in "", client: 192.168.247.15, server: ~^(backoffice\.)(?<domain>.+)$, request: "GET /atlas/assets/main.css HTTP/1.1", host: "backoffice.local.upowr.io", referrer: "https://backoffice.local.upowr.io/atlas/?latitude=-32.912492&longitude=151.314799&roof_id=c0876d8d-8712-464e-8815-b963d675e8ea&phase_num=1&task_mode=true"
```

But an almost equivalent location definition /atlas-og/ which does use variables but does not use a second level of indirection to configure the proxy_pass directive works just fine.

Why?

```
 location /atlas/ {
        rewrite ^/atlas/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        set $proxy_pass $ATLAS_UI_ENDPOINT$uri$is_args$args;
        proxy_pass $proxy_pass;
    }

    location /atlas-og/ {
        rewrite ^/atlas-og/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_pass $ATLAS_UI_ENDPOINT$uri$is_args$args;
    }
```

**Update**

```
location /atlas/ {
    rewrite ^/atlas/(.*)$ /$1 break;

    proxy_pass $ATLAS_UI_ENDPOINT;
}

set $proxy_pass_outer $ATLAS_UI_ENDPOINT;

location /atlas-outer/ {
    rewrite ^/atlas-outer/(.*)$ /$1 break;

    proxy_pass $proxy_pass_outer;
}

location /atlas-inner/ {
    rewrite ^/atlas-inner/(.*)$ /$1 break;

    set $proxy_pass_inner $ATLAS_UI_ENDPOINT;
    proxy_pass $proxy_pass_inner;

}
```

So, the first two work, but the third one doesn't.

It seems that proxy_pass can't use variables defined in the location directive and, indeed, nginx warns about this:

```
backoffice  | 2024/03/13 00:53:32 [warn] 17#17: *23 using uninitialized "proxy_pass_inner" variable, client: 192.168.247.15, server: ~^(backoffice\.)(?<domain>.+)$, request: "GET /atlas-inner/?latitude=-32.912492&longitude=151.314799&roof_id=c0876d8d-8712-464e-8815-b963d675e8ea&phase_num=1&task_mode=true HTTP/1.1", host: "backoffice.local.upowr.io"
```

So the problem comes down to this. Why does proxy_pass respect variables set in the server scope but not in the location scope?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally worked it out.

The order of the set directive with respect to the rewrite directive is important.

```
location /atlas-fixed/ {
        set $proxy_pass_inner $ATLAS_UI_ENDPOINT;
        rewrite ^/atlas-inner/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_pass $proxy_pass_inner;

        include includes/location/backoffice.conf;
        include includes/policy/do-not-preserve-host-header.conf;
}
```

whereas this is broken:

```
location /atlas-broken/ {
        rewrite ^/atlas-inner/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        set $proxy_pass_inner $ATLAS_UI_ENDPOINT;

        proxy_pass $proxy_pass_inner;

        include includes/location/backoffice.conf;
        include includes/policy/do-not-preserve-host-header.conf;
}
```

Englightenment dawned when I read this comment:

> Note that nginx configuration is declarative, not imperative, and set ... is actually takes place during ​processing of rewrite module directives. This happens just after selecting appropriate location and before access checks, notably auth_request.

https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/2294